# Findind an SQL solution to basic set theory idea

Tags: sql, select

I have a database table that is as follows:

```
╔═════════════════╦════════════╗
║ ADVERTISEMENTID ║ CATEGORYID ║
╠═════════════════╬════════════╣
║               1 ║ A          ║
║               1 ║ C          ║
║               2 ║ A          ║
╚═════════════════╩════════════╝
```

This basically means that:

- advertisement **#1** belongs to two categories: **A** and **C** and
- advertisement **#2** belongs to one category: **A**.

Say a user passes a parameter of possible categories of (**A,B,C**). Here both advertisements match because the set of possible categories contains all of advertisement **#1**'s categories and the set of possible categories contains all of advertisement **#2**'s categories.

However, if a user passes as a parameter another set of possible categories such as (**A,D**). Here only advertisement **#2** matches and ad **#1** does not match because the set of possible categories does not contains all of **#1**'s categories.

Now I am not sure how to express this in SQL i.e. build a SQL query that retrieves the distinct advertisment IDs from the table given a parameter of possible category IDs.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possible solutions on this problem, but the one I'm using is by filtering the results in the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT  advertisementID
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY advertisementID
HAVING  SUM(CASE WHEN CategoryID IN ('A','B','C') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
        SUM(CASE WHEN CategoryID NOT IN ('A','B','C') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*for A, B, C*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e16ef/2)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*for A, D*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e16ef/3)

Brief Explanation,

```
SUM(CASE WHEN CategoryID IN ('A','B','C') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

What it does is it *counts* the `CategoryID` that matches on the list given. It should have atleast one match from the list. The other one,

```
SUM(CASE WHEN CategoryID NOT IN ('A','B','C') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

It counts all the `CategoryID` that doesn't match on the given list. This time, this should have a value of zero in order to be filtered on the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed reply JW! I was actually looking for something simpler that I could port to JPQL (Java Persitence API). Can you please very briefly describe the other possible solutions you are hinting at?

Comment: @balteo other solutions are using `EXISTS`, `JOIN`.

Comment: May I know what lacking in my answer? I mean there's nothing wrong with unaccepting it but maybe I need some explaination so I can improve my answer..

Answer (score 2):

This is what a refer to as a sets-within-sets problem.  I think the best way to find a match on any of the categories is the following approach:

```
select ADVERTISEMENTID
from t
group by ADVERTISEMENTID
having sum(case when categoryid = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
       sum(case when categoryid = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
       sum(case when categoryid = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

In other words, this is aggregating by `advertisementid` and doing a separate comparison on each category value.  The `sum()` statements are counting the number where it is present.  The `or` is saying the any of these must be true.

For a subset relationship, I add one more clause to count the non-matches:

```
select ADVERTISEMENTID
from t
group by ADVERTISEMENTID
having (sum(case when categoryid = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
        sum(case when categoryid = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
        sum(case when categoryid = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
       ) and
       sum(case when categoryid in ('A', 'B', 'C') then 0 else 1 end) = 0
```

The reason I prefer this method is because it is quite expressive.  If we change the `or` to `and`, then we are asking for all of the three categories:

```
select ADVERTISEMENTID
from t
group by ADVERTISEMENTID
having sum(case when categoryid = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when categoryid = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when categoryid = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

If we wanted at least two matches from the set, we could add `count(distinct)`:

```
select ADVERTISEMENTID
from t
group by ADVERTISEMENTID
having (sum(case when categoryid = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
        sum(case when categoryid = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
        sum(case when categoryid = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
       ) and
       count(distinct categoryid) >= 2
```

And so on.

Comment: I was also thinking about this but the problem of the first query you showed is that ***it should have all*** the `categoryID` present on the list (*which the user don't want, I think, by understanding the examples given*) and which is very the same with `SELECT ADVERTISEMENTID FROM t WHERE CategoryID IN ('A','B','C')  GROUP BY ADVERTISEMENTID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CategoryID) = 3`, right?

Comment: hehe maybe the OP lack better explanation on the subject `+1`

Answer (score 1):

Using the schema from @JW in the sqlfiddle, another solution is:

```
SELECT matchacat.advertisementID
FROM   (select distinct advertisementID
        from   TableName
        where  CategoryID in ('A', 'D')) AS matchacat
LEFT JOIN
      (select distinct advertisementID
      from   TableName
      where  not CategoryID in ('A', 'D'))AS notmatch
ON    (matchacat.advertisementID = notmatch.advertisementID)
WHERE notmatch.advertisementID is null
```

So, get the set of ads matching at least one cat, then get the set of ads which have a non-matching cat and use the outer join to remove the second set from the first set.